# How can I prevent my columns from stacking when the browser viewport shrinks

Tags: css, flexbox

Instead of having my columns from stacking when the browser viewport shrinks, I want the columns to remain as they are but have a horizontal scroll bar to appear so people on smaller devices can just swipe right to scroll.

Is this possible since I am using flex?

```css
body {
      color: #333;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.board-container {
  background-color: rgb(0, 121, 191);
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#board-surface {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

#board-surface, body, html {
    height: 100%;
}


#content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  outline: none;
}

.board-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.board-main-content {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-right: 0;
    transition: margin .1s ease-in;
}


.board-canvas {
    position: relative;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

/*#board {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}*/

.list-wrapper {
  width: 272px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.list {
    background: #e2e4e6;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    white-space: normal;
}


.list-card {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    max-width: 300px;
    min-height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="board-container">
  <div class="board-inner">

    <div id="board-surface">
      <div id="header">
        main header goes here
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        <div class="board-wrapper">
          <div class="board-main-content">
            <div class="board-header">board header</div>
            <div class="board-canvas">
              <div id="board">
                

                <div class="list-wrapper">
                 
                  <div class="list">
                    <div class="list-header">list header</div>
                    <div class="list-cards">
                      <div class="list-card">
                        this is a list card
                      </div>

                       <div class="list-card">
                        this is a list card
                      </div>

                       <div class="list-card">
                        this is a list card
                      </div>

                       <div class="list-card">
                        this is a list card
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div> <!-- /list-wrapper -->



                <div class="list-wrapper">
                 
                  <div class="list">
                    <div class="list-header">list header</div>
                    <div class="list-cards">
                      <div class="list-card">
                        this is a list card
                      </div>

                       <div class="list-card">
                        this is a list card
                      </div>

                       <div class="list-card">
                        this is a list card
                      </div>

                       <div class="list-card">
                        this is a list card
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div> <!-- /list-wrapper -->




                <div class="list-wrapper">
                 
                  <div class="list">
                    <div class="list-header">list header</div>
                    <div class="list-cards">
                      <div class="list-card">
                        this is a list card
                      </div>

                       <div class="list-card">
                        this is a list card
                      </div>

                       <div class="list-card">
                        this is a list card
                      </div>

                       <div class="list-card">
                        this is a list card
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div> <!-- /list-wrapper -->


                <div class="list-wrapper">
                 
                  <div class="list">
                    <div class="list-header">list header</div>
                    <div class="list-cards">
                      <div class="list-card">
                        this is a list card
                      </div>

                       <div class="list-card">
                        this is a list card
                      </div>

                       <div class="list-card">
                        this is a list card
                      </div>

                       <div class="list-card">
                        this is a list card
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div> <!-- /list-wrapper -->




              </div> <!-- /board-->


            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add an inline MCVE snippet

Answer (score 0):

DEMO: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wxJGMx?editors=0110

I was able to achieve a horizontal scroll on flex container. I've given min-width to .list-wrapper and have added the below styles to #board item:

```css
.list-wrapper {
  min-width: 272px;
  width: 272px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

#board {
  display: flex;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```